# Making a date vector start from specific date and go n units forward

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

In order to use ggplot to work with time-series I need to take a bunch of forecasted values and put them into a dataframe together with the corresponding dates.

I have used the following code to declare my initial vector a ts

```
name <- ts(name, frequency=12, start=c(2007,1))
```

I then fit the model using

```
fit <- auto.arima (name)
```

and extract prediction and prediction intervals as follows

```
name.for <- forecast(fit, 15)
name.for.low <- name.for$lower[,2]
name.for.up <- name.for$upper[,2]
```

I know hope to make a vector of dates, which starts where the time-series declared above ends and go forward *n* months

I guess I can use something like:

```
seq(as.Date('X'), length.out=n, by='1 month')
```

However, I want X to be dynamic, and be calculated from the time-series vector above

Comment: The `forecast` package has some `autoplot` functions which allow `ggplot2` to work with time series.

Comment: Hey @RobHyndman, yeah I found those. However, in the end I ended up using the following [link](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasts-and-ggplot/) on your website. 

First, I couldn't get it to work, but there was a comment below reporting a bug, which fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(lubridate)
jan31 <- ymd("2016-01-31")
n <- 4
jan31 %m+% months(n)
#[1] "2016-05-31"
n <- 5
jan31 %m+% months(n)
#[1] "2016-06-30"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
ts2<- ts(1:28, frequency=12, start=last(time(name )) )
as.Date(ts2)
```

Edit: if you want it to start from next month then add the fractional frequency to start 
`ts2<- ts(1:28, frequency=12, start=last(time(name )+1*deltat(name)) )`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I will post in a sec how I solved it in the original post

Comment: [Edited] It's working for me. as.Date.ts being picked from package zoo.  One difference might be that I am picking name as `name <- ts(1:28, frequency=12, start=c(2007,1))` and using it right after this .